# How to close my mobile menu when link is clicked without it conflicting with the desktop menu?

Tags: jquery

Firstly I'am getting it to work on the mobile perfectly.However when i resize to desktop version it fidgets because my j-query is working on the larger screen size as well. How do i find a way around this?

This is the code i used:

```
$('ul.nav a').click(function () {
    $('nav').slideToggle(200, function () {
      $('nav').toggleClass('close').css('display', '');
    });
  });
```

Comment: you add a class to the navigation when you are on the mobile and bind the click event to that class

Comment: Im not sure i get what you mean remember i need it on the achor tags of the html? How do i do what youre talking about